# Is there any open source solution or quick start to start with tag-based record systerm other than my existing 4 table system I use?

Tags: php, mysql, combinations, keyword-search

I have tables like below;

I have 4 MySQL tables like this;

**Table1**

```
========================
id1  |   brand   |  tags
========================
111  | mercedes  | xx
-----+-----------+------
222  | mercedes  | yy
-----+-----------+------
333  | ford      | xx,yy
-----+-----------+------
444  | audi      | yy,zz
-----+-----------+------
555  | jaguar    | xx,yy,zz
========================
```

**Table2**

```
========================
id2  |  model    |  id1
========================
aaa  | s class   | 111
-----+-----------+------
bbb  | figo      | 333
-----+-----------+------
ccc  | a6        | 444
-----+-----------+------
ddd  | xf        | 555
-----+-----------+------
eee  | a4        | 444
========================
```

**Table3**

```
============
id1  |  id3
============
111  | xx
-----+------
222  | yy
-----+------
333  | xx
-----+------
333  | yy
-----+------
444  | yy
-----+------
444  | zz
-----+------
555  | xx
-----+------
555  | yy
-----+------
555  | zz
============
```

**Table4**

```
==================
id3  |  tagdetails
==================
xx   | description
-----+------------
yy   | description
-----+------------
zz   | description
==================
```

My intention is combination search. I use PHP + MySQL. I am fetching records with tags I give as input. For example, when I give `xx`, I will get `mercedes`, `ford` and `jaguar`. When I give `xx,yy,zz`, i get `jaguar` alone. This is an very inefficient solution when there is a huge number of records. Is there any free to use existing similar solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you should not store the car names as CSV data, but rather break them out into separate records.  But do you have another question, or if not then why did you post those other tables?

Comment: I posted the entire tables to show that I am not posting this question to use SO as my PRA. I am currently using this solution, and like u said, I understand that this is not efficient. I am asking if there is some efficient solution ready available so that I can customize it according to my requirement, like "Apache Ignite" for caching.

Comment: Are you asking about ways to speed things up without changing your schema, or are you looking for ways to improve your design?

Comment: I am completely ok to change my schema, or to introduce other technologies like Java or some open source solution, which can improve my design, and performance.

Comment: My goal is to achieve tag combination search (like tags in SO)

Comment: I think if you just do away with that CSV data you should already by 50% of the way there.

Comment: I am not doing search in "Table1". Keywords are given there for me to get an idea about the tags related to that entry. I does my search in "Table3" and the rows are mapped accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SET` column for this type of application. When you create the column you specify a list of up to 64 possible values the column can contain, however in the database these are stored as a binary bit set, so first item is 1, second is 2, third is 4, 8, 16, 32 etc.

You can access them by name or numerically and search using `LIKE` against the text values or using all the bit operators. The beauty of a bit set is every possible combination of tags will have a unique number. If `xxx = 1` and `yyy = 2` then a car with both will tags will `= 3`.

Assuming your table structure posted here is accurate then the following will add the necessary columns and compute the values for everything:

```
SELECT @tags:= GROUP_CONCAT(id3 SEPARATOR '", "') FROM table4;
SET @s = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE table1 ADD tagset SET("', @tags, '")');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
ALTER TABLE table4 ADD tags int NULL;
SET @tags:= NULL;
UPDATE table4 SET tags = (SELECT (@tags:= IF(@tags IS NULL, '1', @tags * 2)));
UPDATE table1 SET tagset = tags;
```

This adds a column to table4 with the numeric values for each tag and a `SET` column to table1 with the correct tags set. You then structure yur queries to calculate the correct values based on the tag name.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tagset = (SELECT SUM(tags) FROM table4 WHERE id3 IN ('xx', 'yy'));
// Using '=' will only return matches with tag xx and yy exactly

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tagset & (SELECT SUM(tags) FROM table4 WHERE id3 IN ('xx')); 
//  Using '&' will return all matches with xx
```

All other bit comparison operators can be used. More info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html)

There's a demo sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15cffd/13)